# Session Manager Alamofire Response Data

Tags: ios, swift, networking, alamofire

I try to use Alamofire.SessionManager for retry request and offline manager, and I get problem with catch offile mode.

If I use request like this:

```
Alamofire.SessionManager.default.request("www.google.pl").responseData(queue: queue) { (data) in  
print(data)
}
```

When is no internet connection, data doesn't print (response Data handler doesn't call) and if it is connected, work perfectly.

Comment: what is the queue value?

Comment: DispatchQueue(label: "com.cnoon.response-queue", qos: .userInitiated, attributes: .concurrent)